# SQL insert a category named “Guitars” into Categories table. Procedure not working

Tags: sql

I'm working on a school assignment that wants me to insert some new values into a database table and then print a message based on whether or not the `INSERT` was successful. This procedure should attempt to insert a new category named `Guitars` into the `Categories` table. If the insert is successful, the procedure should display this message:

> 1 row was inserted.

If the update is unsuccessful, the procedure should display this message:

> Row was not inserted - duplicate entry:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE test()
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON ;
BEGIN 
  INSERT INTO categories 
              (category_name, category_id) 
              VALUES 
              ('Guitars', 1 ); 

  COMMIT; 
  dbms_output.put_line('1 row inserted.'); 
  exception 
WHEN others THEN 
  dbms_output.put_line('Row was not inserted - duplicate entry.'); 
END ;
DELIMITER ;
CALL test();
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: This has elements of mysql and oracle code - you cannot mix and match like this what dbms are you using.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product and stored procedures are highly vendor specific. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using